# Can't modify "Kernel Configuration Options"

Tags: kernel, configuration

Immediately after adding a kernel using the `Evaluation --> Kernel Configuration Options`, I cannot further modify the list of kernels in that configuration panel (neither delete nor add). The kernels listed can be used properly though.

I wonder why? Currently I'm running Mathematica 12 on a MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Bug. Report to Wolfram.

Comment: @user6014 Ok. That's unfortunate.

Comment: I met the same trouble, and had no idea to deal with it, after reinstalling MMA, the trouble gone.

Comment: @ZoeRowa Thanks! I'll give it a try